Marrying cousin's daughter
Assalamu Alaikum,
I want to know whether I can marry my niece who is the daughter of my cousin brother's (My father's sister's son's daughter)?
I know there are many previous answers but I dont think they say what I ask....
Cause this niece is my cousin's daughter not siblings daughter

The linked duplicate lists all those women who are forbidden to marry. If you don't see something in that list then it should be understood that that case is permissible to marry. Cousins themselves are permitted to be married so any further relationship is also permitted to be married.  Fatimah, the daughter of the Prophet ﷺ, married her father's cousin, Ali ibn Talib.
